# Math in text when using definitions based on intervals and limits

Tags: math-mode, text, inline, units

Should intervals/limits that are part of a definition in a text section be written using inline math mode? And in that case, how should it be written, and should the marker (BMI) and unit (kg/m^2) be included in the math mode?

Example (one sentence from a longer section in my report):
"As overweight is defined by BMI 25-30 kg/m^2, this means that BMI>=25kg/m^2 is in the range of overweight and obesity"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! <limits can be simple written for example as `\lim_{0\to 1}`, for units  I sugest to use `siunitx` package, for example ˙\qty{35}{\kilo\gram\per\square\meter}` or \qty{35}{\kilo\gram/\square\meter} or ... It can be place in equation. For more, please provide a small doxument with example what you describe in question ...

Comment: If you write a sentence like this where "BMI" is used as abbreviation for an actual word, I would rather not use real inline math, but just write `... means that BMI $\geq$ \qty{25}{\kilo\gram/\square\meter} is in ...` using the `siunitx` package as suggested by Zarko. However, one could argue that the spacing greater-than sign is not optimal then.

Comment: Thanks both. I will use the siunitx package and the \qty and \qtyrange. @Jasper, what do you mean about the spacing greater-than sign? Should the space between \geq and \gty optimally be omitted?

Comment: No, it should be there, but there is a small difference between the output of `BMI $\geq$ \qty{25}{\kilo\gram/\square\meter}` and of `$\text{BMI} \geq \qty{25}{\kilo\gram/\square\meter}$`: The math spacing is slightly narrower.